# auto refresh data of excel/csv file from specific folder of local drive into google drive/google sheet

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, export-to-csv

how to auto refresh excel/CSV data of specific folder pc local drive into google drive by pasting newly updated data into a folder

im want when being download a new updated file of excel/CSV file and copying and pasting this file data into a specific folder of the local drive it auto-refresh this data on google drive/google sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Drive for Desktop to accomplish this which is Google's official tool for syncing Google Drive with the local files in your PC. According to Google's documentation:

> If you edit, delete, or move a file in one location, the same change happens in the other location. That way, your files are always up to date and can be accessed from any device.

You just need to install it to your PC, then add your Google account to it and your files will appear in a local folder with a Google Drive logo on it.

Please note that depending on how you want to manage your files you will be presented with 2 different options:

1. Mirroring.
2. Streaming.

Mirroring is basically storing the files in both the cloud and in your hard drive at the same time for offline access.

Streaming is just having the files stored in the cloud but accessible from your PC when connected to the internet. Files will only take storage from your PC when you edit them or make them available offline.

#### References:

- [Install and set up Google Drive for desktop](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/13022292)
- [What it means to mirror or stream your files](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124)